# Binary Tree Iterative Inorder Traversal

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-tree, tree-traversal

I'm trying to implement an iterative inorder traversal of a binary tree.

node.py:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, node=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.node  = node
        self.left  = left
        self.right = right
```

inorder_traversal.py:

```
from node import Node

def in_order(root):
    stack = nodes = []
    while stack or root:
        if root:
            stack.append(root)
            root = root.left
        else:
            current = stack.pop()
            nodes.append(current.node)
            root = current.right
    return nodes


def main():
    '''
    Construct the below binary tree:

            15
           /  \
          /    \
         /      \
        10      20
       /  \    /  \
      8   12  16  25

    '''
    root = Node(15)
    root.left  = Node(10)
    root.right = Node(20)
    root.left.left  = Node(8)
    root.left.right = Node(12)
    root.right.left  = Node(16)
    root.right.right = Node(25)

    print(in_order(root))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've been getting: **AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'node'**.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.  Give the entire error message, including the stack trace.  We also expect that you will trace the offending values just before the point of error. Where are you confused about how they got to those values?

Comment: @Prune the example given here seems pretty minimal and reproducible to me...

Comment: @Prune Sorry I just added the `import` statement in the second code block. The stack trace had 3 lines in it which I felt would be unnecessary if added completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stack = nodes = []` creates two references to the same list object.
When you do `stack.append(root)` or `nodes.append(current.node)` this affects both `stack` and `nodes` because they are the same. What you want is 2 different objects:

```
stack = []
nodes = []
```

Then you'll get this output: `[8, 10, 12, 15, 16, 20, 25]`

Answer (score -1):

The value of the node variable is initialized to an Int in your code (e.g. Node(5)) and your in_order method push that value on the stack and later pop it and try to access its node variable, which will result in the error.

Here's an implementation that does not have that error and uses recursion for the in order traversal (which can be simpler to follow).

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value  = value
        self.left  = left
        self.right = right

def in_order(node):
    nodes = []
    if node.left:
      nodes.extend(in_order(node.left))
    nodes.append(node.value)
    if node.right:
      nodes.extend(in_order(node.right))
    return nodes
```

Comment: I was trying to implement an iterative solution.